# NullReferenceException: OneSignal.isValidSuccessFailureDelegate

Tags: unity-game-engine, onesignal

I am using OneSignal SDK Version 2.14.1 and Unity version 2020.3.14f LTS

I get the following error when I try to push a OneSignal notification using the OneSignal.PostNotification() method.

**NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at OneSignal.isValidSuccessFailureDelegate(OneSignal)
at OneSignal.onPostNotificationFailed(OneSignal)**

This used to work fine in the previous edition. I've updated my project from an older version of Unity and the OneSignal package.

```
public void Invite(string toUseID, string message, string data)
{
    var notification = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    notification["contents"] = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "en", message } };
    notification["data"] = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "data", data } };
    // Send notification to this device.
    notification["include_player_ids"] = new List<string>() { toUseID };
    // Example of scheduling a notification in the future.
    // notification["send_after"] = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().AddSeconds(1).ToString("U");

    Debug.Log($"Posting notification now. to : {toUseID}");
    Debug.Log("Data: " + data);
    Debug.Log("notification: " + notification);
    Debug.Log("Notificationcontents: " + notification["contents"]);
    //PlayFabManager.instance.LogEvent(GameEvents.InvitedOfflinePlayers, new EventBody("toID", toUseID));

    OneSignal.PostNotification(notification, (responseSuccess) =>
    {
        Debug.Log($"Notification posted successful!");// \n{Json.Serialize(responseSuccess)}");
    },
    (responseFailure) =>
    {
        Debug.Log($"Notification failed to post");//\n{Json.Serialize(responseFailure)}");
    });

    Debug.Log("Onesignal failed?");
}
```

I've checked the OneSignal GitHub for answers but didn't understand the fix mentioned here, as I couldn't find the code mentioned in the new package.
https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Unity-SDK/issues/300

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Have you done the [**Initialization**](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Unity-SDK#initialization) first ?

Comment: Yeah I have initialized OneSignal at the start

        OneSignal.StartInit(_appID)
            .HandleNotificationOpened(HandleNotificationOpened)
            .HandleNotificationReceived(HandleNotificationReceived)
            .HandleInAppMessageClicked(HandlerInAppMessageClicked)
            .EndInit();`